# How to share to Facebook as an excerpt?

Tags: excerpt, facebook

Doesn't have to be automated. It's just every instruction I read says to just paste a link and wait a fee seconds. For me it doesn't work. It always shows the main page image, instead that of an article I'm sharing. Help please. :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.